# How can I parse data if the data displays after clicking the button when I write something in input

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

There is s website that doesn't have parameters, 
But there will be data if I click the search button after entering the input! 
But I don't have any idea how I can do that, please help me?
Is it possible to do it with beautifulsoup 
If not what can I do it with?

Comment: use can use selenium for dynamic interaction with website like entering details and clicking buttons then scrap the new content with selenium. without code what you tried its hard to help

Comment: aha understood, thanks! yes i did not write any code because the problem was not with code,  you means it is impossible to do it with bs4, Ok i will try Selenium with PyDev then!

Comment: Try Selenium: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: no its not possible with bs4 because bs4 download whole static page and then scrap the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track requests from network tab in developer tools and findout on which path the xhr request is being done. Then you can use [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)